# Understanding $\lim\limits_{m(B) \rightarrow 0, x \in B}$ (Lebesgue Differentiation)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

My question concerns the following excerpt from section 3.1 (Differentiation of the Lebesgue Integral) of Stein and Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*:

> Suppose $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is it true that
> $$\lim\limits_{m(B) \rightarrow 0 \\ x \in B} \frac{1}{m(B)} \int_B f(y) \,dy = f(x), \quad \text{for a.e. } x?\label{1}\tag{$\ast$} $$
> The limit is taken as the volume of open balls $B$ containing $x$ goes to $0$.

My question is: what is the precise meaning of $\lim\limits_{m(B) \rightarrow 0, \, x \in B}$ ?

I am familiar with the following notions of limits:

1. If $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence, then  "$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$" means: for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$.
2. If $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then "$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = y$" means: for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - y| < \epsilon$ whenever $\|x - x_0\| < \delta$.

But \eqref{1} does not seem to match either of the above notions of a limit. My best guess is that \eqref{1} means something like the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{m(B_n)} \int_{B_n} f(y)\,dy = f(x) \quad \text{for a.e. } x$$

for every sequence of balls $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfying (1) $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} m(B_n) = 0$, and (2) $x \in B_n$ for all $n$...Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may phrase it more precisely: For a.e. $x$, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_Bf(y)\,dy-f(x)\right|<\epsilon
\end{align}
whenever $B$ is a ball containing $x$ with measure less than $\delta$. However, we may as well focus only on balls $B_r$ centred at $x$ by asking whether
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{m(B_r)}\int_{B_r}|f(y)-f(x)|\,dy=0.
\end{align}
For each ball $B$ containing $x$, there is some $B_r$ containing $B$ such that $2^{-d}m(B_r)\leq m(B)\leq m(B_r)$ (let $r$ be the diameter of $B$). Then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B|f(y)-f(x)|\,dx\leq\frac{2^d}{m(B_r)}\int_{B_r}|f(y)-f(x)|\,dy.
\end{align}
If the RHS is less than $\epsilon$ whenever $r$ is less than some $r_0$, then just pick $\delta$ small enough such that $m(B)<\delta$ implies $B\subseteq B_r\subseteq B_{r_0}$.

Comment: Thanks! So the conclusion is that  $\lim\limits_{m(B) \rightarrow 0, x \in B} \frac{1}{m(B)} \int_B |f(y) - f(x)| dy$ is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B_r} |f(y) - f(x)| dy$?

Comment: @Leonidas Yes. Back in the years our instructor used Stein, while I mainly relied on Rudin. We actually had this discussion in class. Rudin takes the second approach, but he also discusses so called "nicely shrinking sets", of which balls containing $x$ is a special case.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification! Stein & Shakarchi also mention sets which "shrink regularly to $x$" (Corollary 1.7, p.108). I was actually thinking of making a separate post on that concept, as I didn't quite understand it at first, though after some more thought it's starting to make a bit more sense...